# Can I Create config files with namespaces in Yii2 or do I just create a model from my settings table?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is a question about using config files for my configuration or rather saving the configurations on my settings table on the database. The configurations change as they include usernames and passwords for APIs I am using. I have thought of saving sensitive information to config file and other settings to database. Is it really possible for me to create a config file in `@app\config` folder and declare global variable `$cfg[]` which I can call from all controllers and views? Another question withing this same question is, is it a security risk to use the database for configuration settings like API username and password?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using advanced templates you can use param.php or local-param.phpcper management of global parameters that can be used any place you want. If these parameters are common to both the frontend backend it is appropriate indicate in the \ common.

For storing passwords in the database, or for their conservation in the configuration file param is purely a personal choice. I'm running through the files param very comfortable. The fact of creating a database table its model, controller, and CRUD is very easy with Yii2 especially using the automatic generator gii. Over the years I found the tables of database configurations rather awkward unless you use as structures and key value persistent and also why I found the facilities configuration Yii2 very practical